# D3 - Programmatic control of Brush AND Brush Handle

Tags: d3.js, brush

I am trying to set some limits for brush (and brush handle) behaviour. I want to set a minimum amount between the brush start and brush end.

I started with this:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545

When the user moves the brush. The code changes the transform attributes of the brush handle. This seems to affect the position of the underlying brush as well.

I thought that perhaps just modifying values of:

```
d3.event.selection
```

might work. For example to make sure that the user can never scroll less than 150 pixel, I coded the following:

```
var s = d3.event.selection;
if (s[0] < 150) {
s[0] = 150;
}
```

This works for the brush handle. But does not affect the brush.

I have put the modified MB code at the following location:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fDBdDrfN5kySWDYGzJdR?p=preview

Any general ideas on moving forward would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An extra line as detailed in my amended question above seemed to fix the problem.

In summary:

```
gBrush.call(brush.move, [150, s[1]]);
```

was added to:

```
var s = d3.event.selection;
if (s[0] < 150) {
s[0] = 150;
gBrush.call(brush.move, [150, s[1]]);
}
```

In more detail, the brush handle it seems does not obtain any default control from the mouse via the framework and needs to be told how to move using the following line:

```
handle.attr("display", null).attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + s[i] + "," + height / 2 + ")"; });
```

The brush however, does seem to obtain default control from the mouse via the framework.  So, normally, the brush handle needs to be told how to respond to the mouse while the brush does not.

In a special situation such as programmtically controlling the brush.  Both the brush handle and the brush need to be told how to behave.  The syntax is slightly different for the two elements.

I added an additional line to the snippet above which produced the desired behaviour:

```
var s = d3.event.selection;
if (s[0] < 150) {
s[0] = 150;
gBrush.call(brush.move, [150, s[1]]);
}
```

The call on the brush takes care of its new behaviour.

The change to the s array is then acted upon by the line of code below which changes the brush handle:

```
handle.attr("display", null).attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + s[i] + "," + height / 2 + ")"; });
```

This seems to work.